# Missing Signed in status and acitve user increasing significantly in Firebase Dashboard

Tags: firebase

i just suddenly facing anomaly on my Firebase Dashboard after releasing new build version

1. Signed in Status where i usually filtering active user based on user_id is suddenly missing from the dashboard

[this is the screenshot of my Firebase Project - Production (after new release)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkaqL.png)

it suppose to be like this :

[this is screenshot of my Firebase project - development. (both before and after new release, nothing changed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76wVj.png)

2. the other problem is coming when i look at the number of MAU/WAU/DAU, it was increased significantly within only one day.

active user still in 4.0 Mio
[screenshot before release new version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2oHV.png)

next day after release, active user jump into 5.8 mio
[screenshot after release new version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zDR4.png)

have someone ever faced similar issue and escaping out from this ? please help if you have any solution to fix this issue. this number is invalid and should be reported to management in weekly basis.

thanks for your attention :)